# Is it possible to make a gradient border?

Tags: css, border, gradient

As the title states, is it possible to make a gradient border in CSS3 and if so how?
I know that you can make gradient backgrounds and there are many generators for that, but I am yet to find one that creates the code for a gradient border.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### 1.

Well.. this is no fancy css3 but heres one possible solution:

I made this example for something else before and i just changed the background url of `#childWrap`

http://jsfiddle.net/qD4zd/1/ ( note that the gradient isnt very flexible as it is done with images. )

Basic idea is that if you have element that you want to frame with a border with a gradient, pattern or just image you should wrap that element inside another which you will use as the border.

---

### 2.

A little more flexible gradient: Another thing you might want to try is http://www.css3pie.com and use the gradient background in outer element to create a border like in my example jsfiddle.

OR

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

( http://jsfiddle.net/qD4zd/2/ )

---

### 3.

On a third note.. The first method could be made into more flexible one by using actual `<img>` tag so that you force the image to be specific height and width.. could even look decent.

Comment: +1 for a mix of points 1 & 2, just use a "normal" css3 gradient background on a wrapping element with padding, and put another (non-transparent) background on the inner element

Comment: Yea, Even just css3 background gradient without css3 pie will have more browser support than border gradient.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a possibility to create a gradient shadow border with CSS3:

```
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
   -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -ms-border-radius: 10px;
        border-radius: 10px;

border: 4px solid rgba(0,0,0,.5);
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px #000;
   -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px #000;
    -ms-box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px #000;
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px #000;
```

Practically this will create an inner shadow border with 10px radius at the edges.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing to do much just add following code:

```
 border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, black 0%, white 100%);
  /* border-image-slice: 1;*/
```

just add above code to the element and border-image-slice property will set the inner offsets of the element.

Comment: for browser support add required extension. eg -webkit-border-image

Answer (score 2):

Border with linear gradient.

HTML

```
<div id="input_parameters">
        ...Some HTML...
</div>
```

CSS

```
#input_parameters {
border: 10px solid transparent;

border-image: linear-gradient(#1e2d61 0%,#1f386e 19%,#203c72 20%,#203c73 20%,#266aa8 69%,#2775b5 84%,#2878b9 84%,#2879ba 85%,#297fc0 95%,#2d75ad 100%);

-webkit-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#1e2d61 0%,#1f386e 19%,#203c72 20%,#203c73 20%,#266aa8 69%,#2775b5 84%,#2878b9 84%,#2879ba 85%,#297fc0 95%,#2d75ad 100%);

border-image-slice: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```css
div {
  width: 170px;
  height: 48px;
  border-radius: 24px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-image-source: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff042, #ff5451);
  border-image-slice: 1;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f9e6e6, #c5e0c3), linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff042, #ff5451);
  background-origin: border-box;
  background-clip: content-box, border-box;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div>button</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is an example of a gradient border that would work under Firefox:

```
#gradbor {
    border: 8px solid #000;
    -moz-border-bottom-colors: #555 #666 #777 #888 #999 #aaa #bbb #ccc;
    -moz-border-top-colors: #555 #666 #777 #888 #999 #aaa #bbb #ccc;
    -moz-border-left-colors: #555 #666 #777 #888 #999 #aaa #bbb #ccc;
    -moz-border-right-colors: #555 #666 #777 #888 #999 #aaa #bbb #ccc;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 15px;
}
```

Try something like that in your CSS for it to work.

**EDIT:** I'm not sure if it will work at all on other browsers.

Comment: About your edit, I'd say it doesn't, because of the `-moz-`, which mean the parameters are not accepted as a standard. They are developped by Mozilla for Mozilla browsers. Maybe `-webkit-*` and/or `-o-*`, etc. will work on other browsers. But doubtly the `-moz-*`.

Answer (score 0):

may be other work for you but i have very simple tips for you just replace background-image to border-image like

```css
background-image: -webkit-gradient( linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.10, #124f7e), color-stop(0.90, #3b89c5) );
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center bottom, #124f7e 10%,#3b89c5 90% );
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(90deg,rgb(18,79,126),rgb(59,137,197));
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#3b89c5', endColorstr='#124f7e'); /* for IE */
background-color:#124f7e;

border-image: -webkit-gradient( linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.10, #124f7e), color-stop(0.90, #3b89c5) );
border-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center bottom, #124f7e 10%,#3b89c5 90% );
border-image: -o-linear-gradient(90deg,rgb(18,79,126),rgb(59,137,197));
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#3b89c5', endColorstr='#124f7e'); /* for IE */
border-color:#124f7e;
```

Answer (score 0):

i used the span element instead to use as border by setting its css property. below is my code

```
<div id="main_container">
        <div class="tl"></div>
        <div class="tr"></div>
        <div class="bl"></div>
        <div class="br"></div>
        <span class="borderH"></span>
        <span class="borderV"></span>
</div>
```

n here is my css -

```
   #main_container{
    position:relative;
    width:480px;
    height:480px;
    background:#f9f9f9;
    border:1px solid #ff0000;
    left:20%;
    top:100px;
}
.tl { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; /*background: #ff0000;*/ border-right:1px none #000;width:50%;height:50%;  }
.tr { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 50%;/*background: blue;*/ border-bottom:1px none #000;width:50%;height:50%;}
.bl { position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 0; /*background: yellow;*/ border-top:1px none #000;width:50%;height:50%; }
.br { position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; /*background: #80ff80;*/border-left:1px none #000;width:50%;height:50%; } 
.borderH{
    position: absolute; left: 0; top: 50%;height:1px;width:100%;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #ff0000 , #80ff80); /* For Safari */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(right, #ff0000, #80ff80); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #ff0000, #80ff80); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff0000 , #80ff80); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
}
.borderV{
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 50%;width:1px;height:100%; 
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ff0000 , #80ff80); /* For Safari */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #ff0000, #80ff80); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #ff0000, #80ff80); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ff0000 , #80ff80); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
}
```

this code will generate the output like this https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2sRswnexZtfUVlTM0t2dWI3cjA/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that creates a **colorful gradient border**, like you can see at the top of sites such as Gumroad or Vimeo, e.g.:

[image: Gumroad screenshot: colorful border]

```
<div class="u-border-top-rainbow">Lorem ipsum fu fu ma li ma coco go yo.</div>
```

```
.u-border-top-rainbow {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 30px 0 0 0;

   /* For a gradient repeated 3 times */
  border-image-source: repeating-linear-gradient(to right,
    hsla(   8,  78%, 63%, 1.00 ) 00.00%,
    hsla(   8,  78%, 63%, 1.00 ) 03.03%,
    hsla(   9,  85%, 58%, 1.00 ) 03.03%,
    hsla(   9,  85%, 58%, 1.00 ) 06.06%,
    hsla(  12, 100%, 47%, 1.00 ) 06.06%,
    hsla(  12, 100%, 47%, 1.00 ) 09.09%,
    hsla( 352,  70%, 47%, 1.00 ) 09.09%,
    hsla( 352,  70%, 47%, 1.00 ) 12.12%,
    hsla( 355,  76%, 38%, 1.00 ) 12.12%,
    hsla( 355,  76%, 38%, 1.00 ) 15.15%,
    hsla(   2,  78%, 32%, 1.00 ) 15.15%,
    hsla(   2,  78%, 32%, 1.00 ) 18.18%,
    hsla( 183, 100%, 30%, 1.00 ) 18.18%,
    hsla( 183, 100%, 30%, 1.00 ) 21.21%,
    hsla( 183,  95%, 27%, 1.00 ) 21.21%,
    hsla( 183,  95%, 27%, 1.00 ) 24.24%,
    hsla( 183, 100%, 22%, 1.00 ) 24.24%,
    hsla( 183, 100%, 22%, 1.00 ) 27.27%,
    hsla(  43,  92%, 54%, 1.00 ) 27.27%,
    hsla(  43,  92%, 54%, 1.00 ) 30.30%,
    hsla(  38, 100%, 48%, 1.00 ) 30.30%,
    hsla(  38, 100%, 48%, 1.00 ) 33.33%
  );

  border-image-slice: 1;
}
```

[Codepen: *Colorful CSS gradient border, à la Gumroad or Vimeo*](https://codepen.io/fabswt/pen/JqdomQ)

The gradient *could* be written in half the size with the double stop notation, in this fashion:

```
background: linear-gradient(to right, red 20%, orange 20% 40%, yellow 40% 60%, green 60% 80%, blue 80%);
```

…unfortunately, such syntax is not supported by Safari as of yet.

Answer (score 0):

Just use ::before

```
.card::before{
           content: '';
          width: 100%;
          position: absolute;
          height: 5px;
          top:0;
          left: 0;
          border-radius:5px 5px 0 0;

          background-color: hsl(195, 100%, 50%);
    }
```