# How to apply gradient to the border of a div?

Tags: css, gradient, border-layout

How can I appply gradient to the border of a div using CSS ? Any one example please. I have tried using google, but not able to do it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to make a gradient border with css3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6619818/is-it-possible-to-make-a-gradient-border-with-css3)

Comment: css-tricks has good video/demos on border gradients...http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/95-a-tale-of-border-gradients/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the trick is to **use a wrapper and had an background image to it**, so it's IE7+ proof

```
<span class="buttonWrapper">
   <input type="button" value="Submit" />
</span>
```

**live** [example on JsBin](http://jsbin.com/eqegiw/edit#javascript,html,live)

Comment: I wanted it using CSS and not image.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/nicktheandroid/b875w/1/

check out my demo, i'm in the process of trying to get the gradient to only be on the right border, not the others.