# Cross browser border gradient

Tags: css, cross-browser

I want to get border gradient (from top: #0c93c0; to bottom: white). I wonder, is there any way to get it with css3 for both webkit and moz browsers?

Comment: This seems to cover it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717127/css3-gradient-borders

Comment: it is only for -moz browsers. it doesn't cover webkit

Comment: So just add another declaration for WebKit?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6619818/is-it-possible-to-make-a-gradient-border-with-css3/6620749#6620749

Comment: @L0rdDEVdem0rt: Read through all the answers, it does.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS3 cross browser linear gradient](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546638/css3-cross-browser-linear-gradient)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of borders, I would use background gradients and padding. same look, but much easier, more supported.

a simple example:

```
<div class="g">
    <div>bla</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.g {
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0c93C0, #FFF); 
  background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0c93C0, #FFF); 
  background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, #0c93C0, #FFF); 
  background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #0c93C0, #FFF); 
  background-image:         linear-gradient(top, #0c93C0, #FFF);
  padding: 1px;
}

.g > div { background: #fff; }
```

Comment: @RobW I suppose it's downvoted because lack of elegance (adding extra markup isn't elegant).

Answer (score 2):

Using less.css (of course you can do it without also), the trick is in pseudoselectors (:before and :after):

1. define cross-browser gradient:

```
    .linear-gradient (@dir, @colorFrom, @colorTo) {
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(@dir, @colorFrom, @colorTo);
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(@dir, @colorFrom, @colorTo);
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(@dir, @colorFrom, @colorTo);
        background: -o-linear-gradient(@dir, @colorFrom, @colorTo);
    }
```

2. define border-gradient bundle:

```
    .border-gradient(@colorFrom, @colorTo){
        border-top:1px solid @colorFrom;
        border-bottom:1px solid @colorTo;
        position:relative;

        .border-bundle(@colorFrom, @colorTo){
            position:absolute;
            content:"";
            width:1px;
            height:100%;
            top:0;
            .linear-gradient(top, @colorFrom, @colorTo);
        }

        &:before{ .border-bundle(@colorFrom, @colorTo); left: 0; }
        &:after { .border-bundle(@colorFrom, @colorTo); right:0; }  
    }
```

We can use it now like this:

```
    .some-class{

        /* other properties */

        .border-gradient(#0c93c0, #FFF);
    }
```

Comment: Nice for using Less! Sadly the question doesn't asks for it, so can't upvote. Also, there's an error when adding the last two lines (`&:before [...]` and `&:after [...]`).

Comment: The error is:
No matching definition was found for `.border-bundle(, , , )`

Answer (score 1):

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/9ZDTA/
Add an extra declaration for each browser engine that you want to support, using the specific prefixes.

```
  background-color: #0c93C0; /* fallback color if gradients are not supported */

  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0c93C0, #FFF); 
  background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0c93C0, #FFF); 
  background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, #0c93C0, #FFF); 
  background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #0c93C0, #FFF); 
  background-image:         linear-gradient(top, #0c93C0, #FFF); /* standard, but currently unimplemented */
```

See [this source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-linear-gradient#Cross-browser_gradients).

Comment: what's that? i wanna get `border` gradient. i mean border: 1px, solid ... not `background`

Comment: Border-gradients are not supported yet by Mozilla. I'm showing a cross-browser way to display `background-gradient`s. When Mozilla adds support for border gradients, you use my answer as a base for cross-browser support.