# CSS3 cross browser linear gradient

Tags: css, cross-browser, linear-gradients

What will be Opera and IE alternatives of following code?

```css
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, right top, left bottom, from(#0C93C0), to(#FFF));
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #0C93C0, #FFF);
```

*Note*, I've tested following rules. All browsers supports them. But they are vertical gradients. How can I modify them to horizontal ones?

```css
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0C93C0, #FFF); 
background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0C93C0, #FFF); 
background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, #0C93C0, #FFF); 
background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #0C93C0, #FFF); 
background-image:         linear-gradient(top, #0C93C0, #FFF);
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(right, #0c93C0, #FFF); 
background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(right, #0c93C0, #FFF);
```

All experimental CSS properties are getting a prefix:

- `-webkit-` for Webkit browsers (chrome, Safari)
- `-moz-` for FireFox
- `-o-` for Opera
- `-ms-` for Internet Explorer
- *no prefix* for an implementation which is in full accordance with the specification.

Use `top right` instead of `right`, if you want a different angle. Use `left` or `right` if you want a horizontal gradient.

See also:

- MDN: [`linear-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/linear-gradient)

### Internet Explorer

For <IE10, you will have to use:

```
/*IE7-*/ filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(startColorStr='#0c93c0', endColorStr='#FFFFFF', GradientType=0);
/*IE8+*/ -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(startColorStr='#0c93c0', endColorStr='#FFFFFF', GradientType=0)";
```

`filter` works for IE6, IE7 (and IE8), while IE8 recommends the `-ms-filter` (the value has to be quoted) instead of `filter`.
A more detailled documentation for `Microsoft.Gradient` can be found at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532997(v=vs.85).aspx

### `-ms-filter` syntax

Since you're a fan of IE, I will explain the `-ms-filter` syntax:

```
-ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(
     startColorStr='#0c93c0', /*Start color*/
     endColorStr='#FFFFFF',   /*End color*/
     GradientType=0           /*0=Vertical, 1=Horizontal gradient*/
);
```

Instead of using a RGB HEX color, you can also use a ARGB color format. A means alpha, FF means opaque, while `00` means transparent. The `GradientType` part is optional, the whole expression is case-insensitive.

Comment: `-ms-linear-gradient` doesn't exist. **EDIT**: Until IE10

Comment: Thx very very much. Please take a look at my updated question. There are 5 vertical rules. First 4 are well known: for each browsers stands it's rule.  I wonder, what 5th rule: `linear-gradient` standing for?

Comment: @SLaks: Thats not true! See http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/Graphics/CSSGradientBackgroundMaker/Default.html

Comment: @SLaks so there is no alternative for IE?

Comment: @L0rdDEVdem0rt: -ms-linear-gradient will work with Internet Explorer 10

Comment: what will look like filer alternative?

Comment: your solution for ie doesn't work. It show wrong color and wrong angle. please test it on browser

Comment: are you sure that it's horizontal rule?

Comment: I've provided an excellent link to the documentation at the bottom of my answer. Use `GradientType=1` if you want to have horizontal gradients. At your Question, you mentioned vertical **and** horizontal gradients. For the sake of the example, I had to pick either of the two.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165412/how-to-apply-webkit-gradient-to-ie

Comment: Thanks for this @RobW! However, the first listed IE `filter` property does not validate in CSS 2.1 and yields the following warning: `'filter' is not a known CSS property name.`

Comment: @IanCampbell Even worse, `filter` is also used in the [Filter effects](http://www.w3.org/TR/filter-effects/) specification. I recommend to leave out `ms`, because no sane person is using IE7 any more. IE8 is still used, because it's the last supported IE version on Windows XP.

Comment: Thanks @RobW, and point taken ha -- IE7 is for crazy people ;). I *do* have to support IE8+ though, so I will use `-ms-filter:` and ***not*** use `filter:` as you are suggesting.

Comment: I removed `-image` and still works, so why did you add that ?

Comment: @FranciscoCorrales `background` is a shorthand for `background-image`, `background-color`, etc. `background-image` is more specific than `background`. See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background

Comment: @RobW using firefox 7.0.1 , "background: -moz-linear-gradient(to bottom, #c4daef 15%,#a1bed2 46%,#a1bed2 100%);" is not working.

Answer (score 11):

Here an example, which works with Opera, Internet Explorer and many other web browsers. If a browser does not support gradients, it will show a normal background color.

```
background: #f2f5f6;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f2f5f6 0%, #e3eaed 37%, #c8d7dc 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#f2f5f6), color-stop(37%,#e3eaed), color-stop(100%,#c8d7dc));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f2f5f6 0%,#e3eaed 37%,#c8d7dc 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #f2f5f6 0%,#e3eaed 37%,#c8d7dc 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #f2f5f6 0%,#e3eaed 37%,#c8d7dc 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f2f5f6', endColorstr='#c8d7dc',GradientType=0 );
background: linear-gradient(top, #f2f5f6 0%,#e3eaed 37%,#c8d7dc 100%);
```

I've stolen this from [this](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) website. Microsoft has built their own generator [here](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/Graphics/CSSGradientBackgroundMaker/Default.html).

Comment: What is the difference between -webkit-gradient and -webkit-linear-gradient?

Answer (score 4):

Rob W's answer is comprehensive, at the same time verbose. Therefore I'd like to go for a summary supporting current browsers end of 2014, while ensuring *some* backwards-compatibility at the same time, leaving out just IE6/7's invalid capability of rendering a linear gradient and early Webkit (Chrome1-9, Saf4-5 special way (`-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop( 0, #0C93C0 ), color-stop( 100%, #FFF ) );`)

Standards syntax [has changed](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient#History_of_the_syntax) from beginning gradient position to `to direction`, e.g. `background-image: linear-gradient( to bottom, #0C93C0, #FFF );`

**Widely-supported, easy-to-read CSS:**

```css
background-color: #8BCCE1;                                             /* fallback color (eg. the gradient center color), if gradients not supported; you could also work with an gradient image, but mind the extra HTTP-Request for older browsers */
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorStr=#0C93C0, EndColorStr=#FFFFFF )"; /* IE8-9, ColorZilla Ultimate CSS Gradient Generator uses SVG bg image for IE9 */

background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(       top, #0C93C0, #FFF ); /* Chrome10-25, Saf5.1-Saf6, iOS -6.1, Android -4.3 */
background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(       top, #0C93C0, #FFF ); /* Fx3.6-15 */
background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(       top, #0C93C0, #FFF ); /* Op11.10-12.02 */
background-image:         linear-gradient( to bottom, #0C93C0, #FFF ); /* W3C, Fx16+, Chrome26+, IE10+, Op12.10+, Saf6.1+ */
```

An interesting side fact is, that most blog posts and browser gradient tools on the web, like f.e. famous ColorZilla's "[Ultimate CSS Gradient Generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)" include the MS vendor-prefixed `-ms-linear-gradient` value. 
It's supported from Internet Explorer 10 Consumer Preview on. But when you're including standards value `linear-gradient`, [Internet Explorer 10 Release Preview](https://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/Graphics/CSSGradientBackgroundMaker/Default.html) renders it appropriately.
So by including `-ms-linear-gradient` and standards way, with `-ms` you're actually addressing just IE10 Consumer Preview, which comes down to ***nobody*** in your audience.

Answer (score 2):

I got the solution for almost everything!

```
/* Safari 4+, Chrome 1-9 */                         background-image:   -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#000000), to(#FFFFFF));
/* Safari 5.1+, Mobile Safari, Chrome 10+ */    background-image:   -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #000000, #FFFFFF);
/* Firefox 3.6+ */                                      background-image:   -moz-linear-gradient(top, #000000, #FFFFFF);
/* IE 7-*/                                                  filter:                 progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(startColorStr='#000000', endColorStr='#FFFFFF', GradientType=0);
/* IE 8+*/                                                  -ms-filter:             "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(startColorStr='#000000', endColorStr='#FFFFFF', GradientType=0)";
/* IE 10+ */                                                background-image:   -ms-linear-gradient(top, #000000, #FFFFFF);
/* Opera 11.10+ */                                      background-image:   -o-linear-gradient(top, #000000, #FFFFFF);
/* fallback image                                       background-image:   url(images/fallback-gradient.png);*/
/* fallback/image non-cover color */                background-color:   #000000;
```