# Build JavaScript Object to use with jQuery .css() (what about duplicate keys?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I use jQuery's `.css()` method to apply styles to an element. I do this like so:

```
var cssObj = {
    'background-color' : '#000',
    'background-image': '-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#000,#fff)',
    'background-image': 'linear-gradient(top,#000,#fff)'
};

$(".element").css(cssObj);
```

The problem with this is that obviously I use duplicate keys in the object, which is not cool.

How can I solve this problem? I need to pass the CSS params with duplicate names to address most browsers.

Comment: What about a browser detection script?

Comment: That would work but would not be a nice solution...

Comment: @FishBasketGordo Let's ask [Lex Luthor](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=McAeQiLmEYU) what he thinks about browser detection \o/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Having multiple keys with the same name is not valid, and will generate an error in strict mode.

Create a function/plugin which applies the properties of your `cssObj`. If a string-string pair is found, set a CSS property with the desired value.
If an array is found, loop through it, and update the property with each value. If an invalid value is found, it's ignored.

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/RgfQw/**

```
// Created a plugin for project portability
(function($){
    $.fn.cssMap = function(map){
        var $element = this;
        $.each(map, function(property, value){
            if (value instanceof Array) {
                for(var i=0, len=value.length; i<len; i++) {
                    $element.css(property, value[i]);
                }
            } else {
                $element.css(property, value);
            }
        });
    }
})(jQuery);

// Usage:
var cssObj = {
    'background-color': '#000',
    'background-image': ['-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#000,#fff)',
                         'linear-gradient(top,#000,#fff)']
};
$(".element").cssMap(cssObj);
```

Comment: Great answer, nice technique. Added to favourites for later use.

Comment: Tried this out and it works beautifully, except for Safari 5.0 for some reason...?

Comment: @Owen I have tested it in Safar 4.0.5, 5.0.1 and 5.1.2. These look fine **: http://i.stack.imgur.com/3A3Gs.png** (screenshot)

Comment: @Rob W, sorry for the late reply, using Multi-Safari 4.0.5 on max osx, the jsfiddle returned this black bar: [screenshot link](http://owenhoskins.com/screenshots/cssmap-safari4.0.5.png)

Comment: @OwenHoskins That's because the syntax in the answer is only supported in Safari 5.1. In Safari 4-5.0, `-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#000), color-stop(100%,#fff))` will do the trick. Prior Safari 4.0, gradients weren't even supported. Here's an updated fiddle which includes gradients for all browsers: http://jsfiddle.net/RgfQw/2/ (with exception of IE9-, for which [filters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546638/css3-cross-browser-linear-gradient/7546655#7546655) have to be used).

Comment: @Rob W - Right you are, I wasn't aware of the differences in syntax... thanks for that!!

Answer (score 2):

My advice would be to put your CSS into your stylesheet in it's own class, and simply add that class to your element instead. The browser itself will determine which of the `background-image` properties it supports, and will therefore only render that one.

CSS

```
.gradient-bg {
    background-color: #000;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #000, #fff);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #000, #fff)
}
```

jQuery

```
$(".element").addClass("gradient-bg");
```

Comment: The color values are variables in the real script so this one would not work smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom `$.cssHooks` ([more info](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.cssHooks/)) that determines which one is the correct form, 
by doing various tests --- or you could just use a css class with `$.fn.addClass`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a repository of cssHooks on github for most properties. Writing your own hook is tricky, lots of edge cases.

https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-cssHooks

For background image gradient, you'd need:

https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-cssHooks/blob/master/gradients.js

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you imply that `.css()` method works like CSS attributes in a .css file. I don't think it works like that. But here are few alternatives:

1. Use browser sniffing (why not? you already doing multi-browser CSS with vendor prefixes)
2. Use actual stylesheet linked as `<link />` tag
3. Create `<style>` tag and add rules to it, dynamically.
4. Use style attribute: `$('#my').attr('style', 'background: ...; bakground: ...; border-radius: ...; -moz-border-radius: ...;');`

Comment: From what I read in the jQuery docs it should work. See .css( map ) on  http://api.jquery.com/css/