# jquery cross browser css3 inline style

Tags: jquery, css

It is possible to get something like this from jquery?

```
<div id="test" style="background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #2F2727, #1a82f7); 
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #2F2727, #1a82f7);"/>
```

When I use:

```
$("#test").css({
   'background': '-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #2F2727, #1a82f7)',
   'background': '-moz-linear-gradient(top, #2F2727, #1a82f7)'
});
```

the result is (in chrome)

```
<div id="test" style="background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #2F2727, #1a82f7); "/>
```

Comment: you can create css class and use addclass method instead of .css

Comment: look like this is an old question but I will share a jsfiddle I've found in the internet which does what you requested : http://jsfiddle.net/barney/D9W4v/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not possible in jQuery, because the keys cannot be duplicated. You have to use [`$.cssHooks`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.cssHooks/) or:

```
$("#test").css('background', '-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #2F2727, #1a82f7)')
          .css('background', '-moz-linear-gradient(top, #2F2727, #1a82f7)');
```

Instead of setting fixed styles using `style`, I recommend to use the `*Class` functions: [`addClass`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/), [`removeClass`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) and [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).

As for the HTML, you have to use the `style` attribute:

```
<div id="test" style="background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #2F2727, #1a82f7); 
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #2F2727, #1a82f7);"/>
```

Comment: I can't use class because values of gradient are dynamically generated

Comment: @galer88 Use the method in my answer, or use [this plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8457479/938089?build-javascript-object-to-use-with-jquery-css-what-about-duplicate-keys).

Answer (score 0):

No, and you shouldn't need to. You can't have multiple values for a single CSS property. That works directly in CSS because the duplicate properties overwrite each other, and in this case is dependent upon the browser. Basically, with that CSS, webkit-based browsers see the webkit-specific property and apply it, then see an unknown property and ignore it. Gecko-based browsers will see an unknown property and ignore it, then see a Mozilla-specific property and apply it.

Try your code in Firefox - I bet it will work just fine, except that it will show the Mozilla property instead of the webkit one.

Also, if this is supposed to be CSS3, you should be able to just use the `linear-gradient` instead of the vendor-specific ones, and then it'll work in all CSS3-compatible browsers as well.

EDIT: Well except `linear-gradient` isn't actually supported. So instead you should use those vendor-specific values and additionally use `-ms-linear-gradient` to support IE, `-o-linear-gradient` to support Opera, and also use `linear-gradient` for future compatibility. ;)

Comment: "you should be able to just use the `linear-gradient` instead of the vendor-specific ones, and then it'll work in all CSS3-compatible browsers as well" Which is as of Q1 2012, effectively, none of them.

Comment: @BoltClock Ok, thanks. Didn't know it wasn't actually supported yet... I had wanted to point out that '-webkit-linear-gradient' and '-moz-linear-gradient' aren't CSS3 properties, they're vendor-specific properties.