# Getting linear gradients to work on IE 8

Tags: internet-explorer, css, linear-gradients

```
body {
    /* Mozilla Firefox */ 
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #FFFFFF 0%, #5EB9FF 100%);
    /* IE10 */ 
    background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, #FFFFFF 0%, #5EB9FF 100%);
}
```

The above code works fine on Firefox and Internet Explorer 10, but neither of them work in IE 8.

Now could you please tell me how to make this code work in Internet Explorer 8?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#5EB9FF', endColorstr='#FFFFFF');
```

**Note:** The previous rule is a *full* rule. Do **not** use it in this way: <strike>`background: filter: ....;`</strike>!

See also: [CSS3 cross browser linear gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7546655/938089?css3-cross-browser-linear-gradient)

Comment: Thanks Rob W for your reply. I tried this- background-image:-ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#5EB9FF', endColorstr='#FFFFFF'); but its not working. Normally I am suppose to see a combination of blue and white color in the background but in the IE 8 its showing kind of grey. thanks

Comment: @black_belt Do **not** use `background: filter:...`. My answer contained the whole rule, and I have successfully tested it. Using `filter`: http://jsfiddle.net/3aFs7/1/ and using `-ms-filter`: http://jsfiddle.net/3aFs7/2/.