# Gradient style in a div background, is not working in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I'm trying to make a nice frame for a logo that will be inserted in a webpage I'm working on. And for some reason IE won't display that div, with the fading color. All I want is a simple gradient in an empty div with predefined dimensions. Google chrome is displaying it just like I want, but IE is not displaying anything. And since I have copied the gradient part from [here](http://gradients.glrzad.com/) without understanding a word, I cannot debug it.

Here is the code (in a very reduced version):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="iso-8859-8-i">
<style>
#headGreen{
    float: left;
    margin: 52px 0px 0px 0px;
    width : 300px;
    height: 30px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(right , rgb(255,255,255) 50%, rgb(68,179,68) 62%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(right , rgb(255,255,255) 50%, rgb(68,179,68) 62%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(right , rgb(255,255,255) 50%, rgb(68,179,68) 62%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(right , rgb(255,255,255) 50%, rgb(68,179,68) 62%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(right , rgb(255,255,255) 50%, rgb(68,179,68) 62%);

    background-image: -webkit-gradient(
        linear,
        right top,
        left top,
        color-stop(0.04, rgb(255,255,255)),
        color-stop(0.82, rgb(68,179,68))
    );
}
#header{
    width: 800px;
    height: 100px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
<div id="headGreen"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm using IE9, but I would like it to work in others also.
Thanks :)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3934693/gradients-in-internet-explorer-9 ? In other words, you can't. Need to use the MSIE filters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-ms-linear` gradient is only available in IE 10.

Use the following:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(startColorStr='#0c93c0', endColorStr='#FFFFFF', GradientType=0);
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(startColorStr='#0c93c0', endColorStr='#FFFFFF', GradientType=0)";
```

- `filter` is supported in IE7-
- `-ms-filter` is recommended in IE8 - 9. Important note: the property value **has to be quoted**.

See [CSS3 cross browser linear gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7546655/938089?css3-cross-browser-linear-gradient) for a detailled explanation on the gradient filter syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Gradients In Internet Explorer going all the way back to Version 6 got you down?

No worries! Check out CSS3Pie.

http://css3pie.com/

Thanks, hope this helps!
Aaron

Comment: This site is grate! I already took another answer that works, but it has some other things I need... Thanks! :)

Comment: I am glad I could help. Enjoy CSS3Pie Martin! :-D. I use it all of the time.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the [Ultimate CSS Gradient Generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) for generating gradients.

It utilizes IE's native filters and ensures compatibility all the way back to IE6. I use this all the time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that IE9 is already supporting this all I found is this:

- http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/Graphics/CSSGradientBackgroundMaker/Default.html

Referring to CSS3 Please IE10 will support it.

- http://css3please.com/

I think the older versions will work as they are :

```
/*IE7-*/ filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(startColorStr='#0c93c0', endColorStr='#FFFFFF', GradientType=0);
/*IE8+*/ -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(startColorStr='#0c93c0', endColorStr='#FFFFFF', GradientType=0)";

  background-color: transparent;
  background-color: rgba(180, 180, 144, 0.6); 
            filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99B4B490,endColorstr=#99B4B490);
            zoom: 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following filter wlil only be read by IE:

```
 #headGreen{
      filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#FFFFFF', endColorstr='#44B244');
 }
```