# background color and ms-linear-gradient issue in IE8 and IE9

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, css, css-transitions

Below are the CSS applied and got this issue,

```
 background-color: rgba(91, 94, 85, 0.5) !important;
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#7F5B5E55,endColorstr=#7F5B5E55);
filter:ms-linear-gradient(startColorstr=#7F5B5E55,endColorstr=#7F5B5E55); /*fix for round corner edges in IE9 and input mess rendering in all IE */
```

image 1 : FF,Chrome & IE 9 working fine

image 2 : IE8 not fine

Im not sure how to fix this input properly in IE8. i guess its happen becoz of filter **filter:ms-linear-gradient**,  if i remove this filter in IE8 background color applying but inputs are messed up as below image.

if i have this filter inputs are rendering properly in IE8 background color not applied as expected

[image: firefox working the inputs visible properly]

[image: IE8 the inputs bg are messed up]

Thanks ,

Nithish

Answer (score 7):

Issues with your code:

- **`background-color: rgba(91, 94, 85, 0.5) !important;`**
  This line seems OK. It's very likely that the `!important` flag is redundant, though.
- **`filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( ... );`**
  This line is also OK, although the [`-ms-filter: "...";` syntax is preferred in IE8+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546638/css3-cross-browser-linear-gradient/7546655#7546655).
- **`filter:ms-linear-gradient(startColorstr=#7F5B5E55,endColorstr=#7F5B5E55);`**
  Here starts the trouble:

  1. Internet Explorer's vendor-prefix is `-ms-`, (with the hyphen at the start).
  2. [`-ms-linear-gradient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh453527.aspx) is a value for **`background`, not `filter`**.
     Also, this value is only supported as of IE 10...
- **`//fix for round corner edges in IE9`**
  Comments in CSS are in this format: **`/* comment */`**.
  No exceptions.

Fix:

```
background-color: rgba(91, 94, 85, 0.5) !important;
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#7F5B5E55,endColorstr=#7F5B5E55);
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#7F5B5E55,endColorstr=#7F5B5E55)";
```

Comment: even i gave -ms-filter same issue happens and sorry tht comment i just updated and its for stackoverflow commenting... and how can i fix this issue for IE8

Comment: @Nithish I've included a fix at the bottom of the answer. Try that one. I've tested it, and it works in IE8, IE7, and even IE6: http://jsfiddle.net/a2NkX/

Comment: background is ok but the thing is input fields are messed up as shown in above image the css are as follows  background-color: rgba(91, 94, 85, 0.5) !important;   filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#7F5B5E55,endColorstr=#7F5B5E55); i removed tht ms-linear-grad filter so tht inputs are not showing as same as image 1 how to i resolve tht

Comment: u can chk the background color missing after applying the ms-linear-grad missing http://jsfiddle.net/a2NkX/1/

Comment: @Nithish Remove that line, and use my original fiddle. `filter:ms-linear-gradient` does **nothing**.

Comment: But in my application that filter[ms-linear-grad] renders the input in IE8 properly as same as in FF...  but the background color missing as in the http://jsfiddle.net/a2NkX/1

Comment: @Nithish Can you show a picture of what you want? `-ms-linear-gradient` is a value for `background`, not for `filter:`.