# create multiple evenly spaced horizontal lines with only css

Tags: css

Is it possible to create multiple horizonal evenly spaced lines using only CSS?  I am trying to replicate the look of a notecard and I would prefer not to use images.  Seems like this should be possible.  It looks like this person accomplished what i want to do, but they are using mozilla specific tags: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PFzFX/92/)

Guess I have to add in code if I include a fiddle link.
The CSS from that page:

```
div {
background: 
-moz-repeating-linear-gradient(center top , #fafafa, #fafafa 22px, #81CBBC 24px) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
border: 1px solid #f6f6f6;
box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
margin: 30px auto;
padding: 22px 15px 40px;
position: relative;
width: 400px;
color: #444;
}
h1 {
    font: 24px/26px 'Helvetica Neue', Arial;
    margin: 0 0 6px;
}
li {
    font: 12px/16px Georgia;
    margin: 0 0 7px;
}

div:before {
    content: '';
    z-index: -1;
    width: 433px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -12px;
    left: 4px;
    height: 190px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  background:    -moz-repeating-linear-gradient(center top , #fafafa, #fafafa 22px, #81CBBC 24px) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    -moz-transform: rotate(-1deg);
}

div:after{
    content: '';
    z-index: -3;
    width: 433px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -18px;
     left: 6px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    height: 190px;

    background:    -moz-repeating-linear-gradient(center top , #fafafa, #fafafa 22px, #81CBBC 24px) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
  -moz-transform: rotate(-1deg);
}
```

Comment: So all you want is someone to update / extend the gradient syntax? http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: I have a half answer, so I'll just comment: if there is, it's probably not cross-browser friendly.  So I'd use `background-image` with a base64-encoded image.  That's technically "pure CSS". :)  (Side note: I'm understanding you want a pure CSS way to render the lines *ON* the note card (where you would write text), not lines *UNDER* the note card representing multiple cards.)

Comment: I like that idea, is there a site that will help me create a base64 encoded image of what I want?

Comment: that is right, lines on the card itself

Comment: Quick google search turns up several tutorials: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/web-designer/how-to-get-the-ruled-paper-background-effect-with-css3/#.

Comment: This may already be answered here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546638/css3-cross-browser-linear-gradient)

Comment: Thanks hthornbloom and Brian, those links are very helpful.  I should be able to figure it out from those 2 links.  I had googled quite a bit, but I guess I used the wrong terms.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PFzFX/104/)

```
box-shadow:0 1px 0 1px #fff, 0 2px 0 1px #ccc, 0 4px 0 1px #fff, 0 5px 0 1px #ccc;
```

Comment: i think he may be lookin for this look, http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2e/Notecard.jpg

Comment: that is correct Cory, maybe this isn't possible with only CSS