# How to make repeating-linear-gradient for a table continue seamlessly over multiple cells?

Tags: css, google-chrome, linear-gradients

I'm having trouble with *repeating-linear-gradient* with tables. Basically, I can't make it look nice with tables, especially on Chrome. Even though I apply said rule to a *tr* element, it looks like *td* elements inherit it and instead of having a continuous stripes, I get 'jagged' ones (=stripes do not continue over cell borders).

```
.striped {
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(
    45deg,
    #FFFFFF,
    #FFFFFF 10px,
    #DDDDDD 10px,
    #DDDDDD 20px
)}
```

Here's a Codepen illustrating the issue:

http://codepen.io/merryprankster/pen/bpeCc

With Chrome, it looks really awful. With Firefox, almost good but not exactly (sometimes the stripes are of different width - off by one pixel - across cell boundaries).

**EDIT**: to clarify, I need to target a specific row, not whole table. So yes, the point about styling a *tr* is actually relevant.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS3 cross browser linear gradient](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546638/css3-cross-browser-linear-gradient)

Comment: @DavidKhasikyan This question is about a specific problem with table styling in google chrome. It is not a duplicate of the given question.

Comment: It's even worse with a 7-character cell. `td {background: transparent}` or none doesn't help. Well...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[This is a confirmed bug in Chrome](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-bugs/Ne65r9y8YYI). Given that it was first reported in 2010 (when Gecko actually had the same bug) and is currently marked `WONTFIX` I wouldn't hold my breath for a real fix. You could open a new bug, it might be 'doable' now.

As a workaround: put the stripes on the `table` so as not to confuse the rendering mechanisms, then instead of styling the rows 'to be striped', *unstyle* the other rows, like this:

```
table.striped {
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(
        45deg,
        #FFFFFF,
        #FFFFFF 10px,
        #DDDDDD 10px,
        #DDDDDD 20px
  );
}
tr:not(.striped) {
  background:white; /* or any color that would normally be behind the table */
}
```

This way it still works as if you're highlighting only the indicated row as you intend. If for some reason there is a non-opaque background behind the unstyled rows you're probably flat out of luck because of this bug.

[Updated codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LByCA). Works identically in IE, FF and Chrome without 'hickups'.

Comment: No reason is given for marking the [Chromium bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=44361) as `WontFix`, I'd suggest opening a new one.

Answer (score 3):

You can define `background-attachment: fixed;` to the `tr`, as you can see on this updated Codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NGaBzP.

```
.striped {
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(
    45deg,
    #FFFFFF,
    #FFFFFF 10px,
    #DDDDDD 10px,
    #DDDDDD 20px
  );
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

This solution was presented by Chris Coyier here https://css-tricks.com/stripes-css/
Look for the **Funky Town** part.

The gradient will stay fixed as you scroll the page, but it's better than a 'jagged' style.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. Not sure why this isn't considered the answer (unless it's just too late)...

Answer (score 1):

Can you move the .striped class to the table instead of the row?

```
<table class="striped">
  <tr >
    <td>hi</td>
    <td>there</td>
    <td>dear css observer</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bcpsy

Comment: Unfortunately no, I need to have a specific row highlighted this way.

Answer (score 0):

The mighty power of `:before/:after`… not so mighty with rows.
Following solution works fine in Fx and Chrome with your simple example (though only with `:after` as there's a strange bug if you use `:before` - see comment in fiddle) but if you add a first non-striped row, then only Firefox plays nice as it allows both `tr { position: relative }` and `table { position: relative }` while Chrome doesn't like the former rule and with the latter it'll obviously stripe the whole table.

**[Fiddle](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xesKJ)**

Relevant CSS:

```
table {
  position: relative;
}
.striped:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; /* Whole area of tr */
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(
        45deg,
        #FFFFFF,
        #FFFFFF 10px,
        #DDDDDD 10px,
        #DDDDDD 20px
    )
}
```

edit: pseudo on first cell of striped row with a 2000% width: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lqDKk (Chrome doesn't like padding in 3rd example while border-spacing is OK. Weird widths on my computer)

Answer (score 0):

You could try breaking `<td>`'s annoying behaviour by changing its displaying mode from `table-cell` to `inline-block`.

The obvious drawback is that a predefined width is needed (per all tds, or per column, or per single td, etc...).

Just check IF this solution breaks something in your layout (but since `<table>` is still `display: table;` and `<tr>` is still `display: table-row`, this change could have minimal to zero impacts, basing on your design).

- [Running demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wiAzK)

```css
td {
  padding : 10px;
  display : inline-block;
    width : 30%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering another question ([Diagonal CSS gradient for <tr> in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25730484/diagonal-css-gradient-for-tr-in-chrome/25730558#25730558)), I found this one, so let me post my answer here too...

I ran into this same issue some time ago... Only solution I found was to make the `tr` a `display:block`. It works, though it can cause some layout issues...

http://jsfiddle.net/p3s3zLja/4/

```
tr {
    color: white;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, blue, red);
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
```