# Diagonal CSS gradient for <tr> in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

I'd like to have a diagonal gradient as the background for table rows. It works fine in Firefox, but in Chrome the gradient is applied to each individual `<td>`. Is there a way or some workaround to get it to work?

[Here's a Fiddle to demonstrate.](http://jsfiddle.net/p3s3zLja/)

[Here's an image of the difference.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UF71B.png)

Comment: This might be related: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=34392

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make repeating-linear-gradient for a table continue seamlessly over multiple cells?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25625216/how-to-make-repeating-linear-gradient-for-a-table-continue-seamlessly-over-multi)

Comment: That question also contains a usable workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this same issue some time ago... Only solution I found was to make the `tr` a `display:block`. It works, though it can cause some layout issues...

http://jsfiddle.net/p3s3zLja/4/

```
tr {
    color: white;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, blue, red);
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
```