# Cross browser linear gradient including IE 8 and less

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cross-browser, linear-gradients

I am looking for a perfect solution for cross browser linear gradient including IE 8 and below support.

this is my current code

```
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, center top, center bottom, from(transparent), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, .6)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(transparent, rgba(0, 0, 0, .6));
background: linear-gradient(transparent, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

I want to generate the same effect for different browsers.
Please let me know how to get the exact same effect on all browsers by adding cross browser css code.

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS3 cross browser linear gradient](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546638/css3-cross-browser-linear-gradient)

Comment: @George Platko: hello George, thanks for pointing me out that question, now I know how to make the gradient cross browser compatible with prefixes. However, since I am completely new to CSS, can you please help me modify my code with the same values using those prefixes and filters and briefly explain how it works !! So that I can get a better understanding. Hope you can give it a shot, thanks man

Comment: All I can see that you need to add is a `-ms-` prefix for your `background`. Add this at the end: `background: -ms-linear-gradient(transparent, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);`